# SQL Segmented Ranking Operation

Tags: sql, transactions, ranking, audit-trail, dense-rank

I am willing to find the rows, which comes immediately after the (latest) row where Text = E.

It is like an transaction log where I want to find what happened exactly after the Text was equals to E. The Date column might be confusing, please only respect the RANK column.

Example:
I want to get the rows 6 (or 6 and 7) and 14 (or 14 and 15) from below table:

Much appreciated.

[image: table]

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery is a simple solution:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date > (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.text = 'E');
```

If you want to use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(case when text = 'E' then date end) as e_date
      from t
     ) t
where date > e_date;
```